# iOS7 Core Data and iCloud as Backup. User's point of view

Tags: core-data, ios7, icloud

I'm working at a library-type Application that uses CoreData. 
This application will be available to iPhone only and I want to use iCloud just as a backup to be sure that if users change device or delete and reinstall the application they can get their original data.

Working with the new CoreData-iCloud setup I see that the configuration is extremely simple. I have just added `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` when I created the persistent store and I listen to three basic notifications form iCloud.

Now my problem is that when I delete my application and I reinstall it, at the first launch of the reinstalled application, data from iCloud takes more than 2/3 minutes to get back to the device.

This is not what users expect... they start using the application and at some point they find their old data. This is extremely strange from the user point of view. Is there a correct way to reload previously stored data or I have to let iCloud decide when to reload them? And in this case how do you manage this situation making users aware of this random update time?

Comment: If all you want is a backup then just put the store in /Documents and it will be backed up using the normal backup.  Using iCloud results in transaction logs being put in iCloud and these are being imported after the app is reinstalled and assuming iCloud is available.

Comment: To perform the backup in this way users have to perform a device sync. I thought that using iCloud it could be a more user-friendly process.

Comment: If the user has enabled backups to iCloud rather than iTunes then it should be automatic, no need to plug in and sync.  But backup to iCloud is not the same as Core Data/iCloud integration which is intended for synchronisation of data between devices.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a backup then just put the store in /Documents and it will be backed up using the normal backup method selected by the user. Using Core Data/iCloud integration is intended for synchronisation of data between devices and results in transaction logs being put in iCloud.  These transaction logs are being imported after the app is reinstalled (assuming iCloud is available).

If the user has enabled backups to iCloud rather than iTunes then backups should be automatic, no need to plug in and sync with iTunes.

Comment: What happens when user deletes the application and installs it again? The database will be erased and after, when user installs the application, it will be recompiled from zero. The DB in the cloud is not reloaded magically. Am I wrong?

Comment: If the file is in the /Documents directory it will be removed and when the application is re-installed a new document will need to be created.  Backups are not restored magically, the user must choose to restore from a Backup and that restores the entire device.